# Liquibase command for generating script in yaml

Tags: mysql, liquibase

When I try to generate liquibase scripts in yaml, I am gettign this error:

> liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No serializers associated with the filename or extension 'changelogs/.struct.yaml'
>       at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:282) ~[liquibase.jar:na]
>       at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1060) [liquibase.jar:na]
>       at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:209) [liquibase.jar:na]
>       at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:132) [liquibase.jar:na]

Here's the command I used:

```
liquibase  --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  
--changeLogFile=changelogs/.struct.yaml 
--classpath=libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar 
--url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:32306/test?user=root&password=somepassword&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"  
--username=root  
--password=somepassword
generateChangeLog
```

I added the snakeyaml-1.25.jar as well. I am running on mac with mysql. I installed liquibase using brew install.

Comment: Bug in Liquibase 3.8.0:
For a workaround until we get this issue resolved please try the following:
The root of the liquibase directory “liquibase-3.8.0-bin”, there is a liquibase bash script called “liquibase”. Edit this file with the following:

Replace the last 4 lines of:

to see the actual command, uncomment the echo line below.
cmd=“java -cp \”$CP\" $JAVA_OPTS liquibase.integration.commandline.Main ${1+$@}"
#echo $_cmd
#echo ""
$cmd
with

java -cp “$CP” $JAVA_OPTS liquibase.integration.commandline.Main ${1+"$@"}

Answer (score 0):

Your file name starts with a dot:

```
--changeLogFile=changelogs/.struct.yaml
```

Change it to something like `db.struct.yaml` or `struct.yaml`